# How to hide the TabView's Toolbar on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I would like to remove the toolbar of a TabView on macOS. Is it possible and how?

[image]

My code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectionIdx = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    selectionIdx -= 1
                    if selectionIdx < 0 {
                        selectionIdx = 0
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrowshape.left.fill")
                })
                Spacer()
                Text("Title")
                    .font(.title)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    selectionIdx += 1
                    if selectionIdx > 2 {
                        selectionIdx = 2
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrowshape.forward.fill")
                })
            }
            .padding()
            TabView(selection: $selectionIdx) {
                Text("Tab1")
                    .tag(0)

                Text("Tab2")
                    .tag(1)

                Text("Tab3")
                    .tag(2)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```